# How to write overload method for e.Graphics.DrawImage ? for that get Image[] ,Point []

Tags: c#, image, printing, graphics, drawimage

Hello I try to print number of images  in same page with my given points

how to write a overloaded function for "e.Graphics.DrawImage"  ?

that overloaded function must gets  Image of array and point of array then  Image[0] set on Point[0] , Image[1] set on Point[1] .....  after that print page

now  draw image function like that  =  e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, Point[]);
 but i need to like that =  e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage[], Point[]);
if wrote before pls  help me

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking. Please clarify your question. Show us what you have tried and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: sory my bad english . can you  read again .

Comment: You can write an extension method on `Graphics` if that is what you are after.

Comment: What is `e` and `Graphics`?

Comment: System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e

Comment: Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(244, 78);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphics class is sealed and not partial, so you can't override or add method to this class. But you can make an [extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for this class

```
public static class GraphicsExtension
{
    public static void DrawImage(this Graphics graphics, Image[] images, Point[] points)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(images[i], points[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

With this extension you can call your implementation of `DrawImage` for `Graphics` instances. For example: `e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Image[1], new Point[1]);`

Comment: thaks for your reply . can you help to me  for where you write "// logic here".it must works like ;   get Image[]  that contains 5 image and point[] that contains 5 point. those images must print on same page

Comment: @çağrıGündüz I put an example, probably it is what you want.